# Why I get error when I submit login form using jQuery Post?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this partial view:

```
@model GeomindEnterprise.Models.LoginViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <!-- /SOCIAL LOGIN -->
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "sky-form", role = "form" }))
        {

            <fieldset class="nomargin">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        <label class="input margin-bottom-10">
                            <i class="ico-append fa fa-envelope"></i>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @placeholder = "Email" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </label>

                        <label class="input margin-bottom-10">
                            <i class="ico-append fa fa-lock"></i>
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { placeholder = "Password" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </label>

                        <label class="form-group">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "col-md-1" })
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </label>

                        <footer>
                            <button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default noradius pull-right"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> OK, LOG IN</button>
                        </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>

        }
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click button submit, this javascript method is called:

```
 function myFunction() {      
        debugger;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: jQuery('form').serialize(),
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                jQuery('#myModalContent').html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
            }
        });
    }
```

The javascript method above calls this action:

```
//
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    //some logic
}
```

When the acction Login is called I get this error:

```
    The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
```

Any idea why I get this error?And how to fix it?

Comment: @adiga, That is not a dupe (the token is included when using `.serialize()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke didn't see the `serialize` part. Will retract the cv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` ajax option, so that you use the default `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"` which you need when using `.serialize()` (note that the token is included in the request when using `.serialize()`)

As a side note, you should be handling the forms `.submit()` event so you can validate the form before submitting. Remove the `onclick="myFunction()"` from your submit button and change the script to

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).valid) {
        return; // cancel the ajax call and display error messages
    }
    ... make ajax call
});
```

You also have `datatype: "json",`, but the fact you also have `$('#myModalContent').html(data);` suggests that your controller method returns html (a `PartialViewResult`), not json, so it should be `datatype: "html",` (or just omit that option and the `$.ajax()` method will work it out)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is.

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

And by doing that (which changes the kind of post request being made), to get the Json content of the actual data property to bind correctly to your T model type DO NOT **JSON.stringify()** or  **jQuery('form').serialize()** the data.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() from your form. it will work for now.How ever it will open you for attacks.
Here is the article on anti forgery token to secure yourself.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks

Comment: Here you can have some post on the same :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks

Comment: No it wont - you cannot use `contentType: "application/json` with `data: $('form').serialize(),`. And what terrible advice to remove the token and open yourself to CSRF attacks

Comment: Yes, I know it is opening to attacks, but I also posted a article to know about the anti forgery token, to secure yourself.

Comment: But you have just told OP to remove the token so they are vulnerable (and that link is for web-api)